# Running Nutch in Eclipse - Missing Build Folder

Tags: java, eclipse, nutch

Hi I was following [this tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/RunNutchInEclipse) trying to run Nutch in Eclipse and run Nutch step by step.

I finished this step (Nutch 1.X) without problem:

```
 svn co https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/nutch/trunk
 cd trunk
```

Since I was working on `1.X`, so I skipped to step#5. However, it mentioned:

`Add “http.agent.name” and “http.robots.agents” with appropiate values in “conf/nutch-site.xml”. See conf/nutch-default.xml for the description of these properties. Also, add “plugin.folders” and set it to {PATH_TO_NUTCH_CHECKOUT}/build/plugins. eg. If Nutch is present at "/home/tejas/Desktop/2.x", set the property to:`

```
 <property>
   <name>plugin.folders</name>
   <value>/home/tejas/Desktop/2.x/build/plugins</value>
 </property>
```

So here is my question:

(1). There is no nutch-site.xml file in the `trunk/conf` folder as default, however, there is a nutch-site.xml.template file which I renamed to nutch-site.xml to use.

(2). `{PATH_TO_NUTCH_CHECKOUT}/build/plugins`, I really don't know where this `build`folder is located. 
This is what I have done:

```
trunk$ find . | grep build
./.svn/prop-base/build.xml.svn-base
./.svn/text-base/build.xml.svn-base
./build.xml
./src/plugin/.svn/prop-base/build-plugin.xml.svn-base
./src/plugin/.svn/prop-base/build.xml.svn-base
...
```

Clearly there is no folder called 'build', neither 'plugins'.

Then should I just take the `./src/plugin` as the `./build/plugins` folder and move on? I don't have that much experience building from source so any advise is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer to your question:

1) Yes. You are correct you have to rename the nutch-site.xml.template file to nutch-site.xml and make the changes accordingly.

2) There is no **/build/plugins** folder currently present. But when you run the **"ant eclipse"** command you will get the **"/build/plugins"** in your **{PATH_TO_NUTCH_CHECKOUT}** 
Thats why it is written as set the absolute path as **{PATH_TO_NUTCH_CHECKOUT}/build/plugins**
Do not give relative path here as it wont.

Hope this helps you!!!